# MariaDB sort string value with faction

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have Linux kernel version like below, want to sort this value from kernel version oldest to latest.

```
4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64
4.18.0-358.el8.x86_64
4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64
4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64
4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64
```

Using this query, its not sorting by kernel version. I expect this line `4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64` should come above last line.

```
select kernel, REGEXP_REPLACE(kernel,'\\.|-|el.*$','') as k from os  group by kernel order by 1;

4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64,4180305191
4.18.0-338.el8.x86_64,4180338
4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64,4180348122
4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64,418034821
4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64,418034871
4.18.0-358.el8.x86_64,4180358
```

How to make this sql query sort by kernel version?

Comment: What do you expect `4.18.0-348.12.2` before `4.18.0-348.2.1` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `4.18.0-348.12.21` should come after `4.18.0-348.2.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this:

```
SELECT kernel,
       k1, k2, k3,
       CASE WHEN k3 LIKE '%-%' THEN 0
        ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(k3,'.',1)+0 END AS k4,
       CASE WHEN k3 LIKE '%-%' THEN 0
        ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(k3,'.',-1) END AS k5
FROM       
(SELECT kernel,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(kernel,'-',1) AS k1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(kernel,'-',-1),'.',1) AS k2,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(kernel,'.el',1),'.',-2) AS k3
 FROM
    os) V
ORDER BY 
  k1, k2, k4, k5
;
```

With a bunch of `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` used starting from the subquery. The idea is to separate a few of the parts from the value where I see it's "orderable". The query above will return the following:

| kernel | k1 | k2 | k3 | k4 | k5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64 | 4.18.0 | 305 | 19.1 | 19 | 1 |
| 4.18.0-338.el8.x86_64 | 4.18.0 | 338 | 18.0-338 | 0 | 0 |
| 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64 | 4.18.0 | 348 | 2.1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64 | 4.18.0 | 348 | 7.1 | 7 | 1 |
| 4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64 | 4.18.0 | 348 | 12.2 | 12 | 2 |
| 4.18.0-358.el8.x86_64 | 4.18.0 | 358 | 18.0-358 | 0 | 0 |

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=e0962ad23c96fb4f0fec0b1dc46b85e0)

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB in 10.7 had a successful trial of [natural_sort_order](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-natural-sort/), soon to be a GA release:

```
MariaDB [test]> create table v( version varchar(30));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into v values ('4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64'),('4.18.0-358.el8.x86_64'),('4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64'),('4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64'),('4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64');

MariaDB [test]> select version from v order by natural_sort_key(version);
+------------------------------+
| version                      |
+------------------------------+
| 4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64 |
| 4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64  |
| 4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64  |
| 4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64 |
| 4.18.0-358.el8.x86_64        |
+------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

ref: has [natural_sort_order](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-natural-sort/)

Comment: good to know, my MriaDB version is 10.5.